# Mandriva 2007 Cannot setup printer

Tags: printing, mandriva

I tried to use a printer that is shared by a Windows PC. When I try to Mandrive Control Center > Hardware > Set up printer, the window opens but there is no content. Only a window. Seems that **`system-config-printer`** package is not installed. I try to open Software Management > Look at instalable ... and select All search by name *system-config-printer* but the search returns nothing.

What should I do next to be able to use the printer?

Comment: It might help to know the Make and Model of the Printer. Some are compatible with Linux. Some are not...

Answer (score 0):

I don't use or know mandriva, but if it is similar to other Linux flavours, you could try it via html in the browser.

Is cupsd up and running?

```
http://localhost:631/admin
```

should be a way to configure cups. Normally you have to have permissions to use cups in the webinterface. Maybe modifications in `/etc/cups/*conf` are necessary, and possible problems are reported in `/var/log/cups/*`.

Answer (score 0):

System-config-printer began being used in later versions of Mandriva.  Back in the 2007 version of Mandrake/Mandriva, you would have to use PrinterDrake to set up your printer and/or use Samba to share the printer out to your Windows clients.

Also, as the unknown user pointed out, cups should be installed and set up properly as well.